# String comparison operator in PHP

Tags: php, function, operators

I have a variable in PHP whose value depends on a input form that user posts.

```
$nhname=$_POST["host"];
```

If the variable 'nhname' contains www in it,then a certain action needs to be taken otherwise something else needs to be done.

I can put it in an if statement and accomplish the above said but I don't know of a PHP operator or function which can check if a string contains a certain sub-string?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to check if a string contains specific words?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4366730/how-to-check-if-a-string-contains-specific-words)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
if (strpos($nhname,'www') !== false) {
    //if it contains www
}else{
    //if it doesnot contains www
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the [strpos()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php) function.

```
if(strpos($nhname, "www.") === FALSE){
    $nhname = "www." . $nhname;
}
```